# Open an empty editor in XCode

Tags: xcode

Sometimes I'll have a blob of text in my clipboard that I want to paste into a text file. Most often I open up another text editor (like TextWrangler) and paste it in there, but it seems a little clunky switching between that and xcode. Is there a way to open an empty text editor in Xcode without creating a new file? I don't want to save anything, I just want to look at the text I've copied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible unfortunately. (as of Xcode 4.4).